# What is the difference (if any) between a postdoctoral fellow and a postdoctoral intern?

Tags: postdocs, titles, terminology

Are "fellowship" and "internship" synonyms? Is there a different meaning in this language, between North America and English-speaking Europe?

Comment: I have never before heard the phrase "postdoctoral intern" outside the field of clinical psychology, and Google search results seem to be with me on this. Where have you heard this phrase?

Comment: Fellow is snazzier (higher honor) than intern. This is based on personal experience in the U.S., in non-medical fields. I don't know about Europe, sorry.

Comment: @ff524 - Can you share the differences you've observed?

Comment: I also have a feeling that a _fellow_ has more reputation than an _intern_... but as a non-native english speaker I am not sure I am getting it right. I didn't find any specific document yet.

Comment: by the way, I am in Quebec, Canada, and here we get an influence from french.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there is none, depending on the field or college.

In the UK, there can sometimes be a distinction. There are certain postdoctoral researcher positions that are positions in a PI's group where one works under a professor or more permanent faculty. A fellowship in the UK system means one has research independence and is allowed to pursue her own research program freely. Sometimes postdoc interns can also do this but it depends on the field, program, and position.